# Capturing PTP packets with Linux raw socket

Tags: linux, ethernet, raw-sockets, bpf

I want to implement a C program that captures all the Precision-Time-Protocol (PTP) frames on the Ethernet, so I created a raw socket and attached a filter for PTP, I use recvmsg() to read data from the socket.
The first issue is that I wasn't receiving any PTP frames so I commented out the filter but now I am not getting any Ethernet frames either.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <linux/filter.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PTP_IF_NAME               "enx503eaa33fc9d"
#define PACKET_SIZE               300
#define NUM_OF_BLOCKS_PER_LINE    30
#define SIZE_OF_BYYE_PRINT_BLOCK  3
#define SIZE_OF_PRINT_BUFFER      \
    ( ( NUM_OF_BLOCKS_PER_LINE * SIZE_OF_BYYE_PRINT_BLOCK ) + 1 )

#define PERROR(x, ...)  printf( x "stderr:%m\n", ##__VA_ARGS__) 
#define INFO(x, ...)    printf( x "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define ERROR(x, ...)   printf( x "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)

int eventSock = -1;

void printBuffer(unsigned char* buffer, size_t len) {
    unsigned char outBuffer[SIZE_OF_PRINT_BUFFER];
    unsigned char* pOutBuffer = outBuffer;
    int usedBytes = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if ((usedBytes + SIZE_OF_BYYE_PRINT_BLOCK) > SIZE_OF_PRINT_BUFFER) {
            INFO("%s", outBuffer);
            memset(outBuffer, 0, sizeof(outBuffer));
            usedBytes = 0;
            pOutBuffer = outBuffer;
        }
        sprintf(pOutBuffer, "%02x ", buffer[i]);
        usedBytes += SIZE_OF_BYYE_PRINT_BLOCK;
        pOutBuffer += SIZE_OF_BYYE_PRINT_BLOCK;
    }
    INFO("%s", outBuffer);
}

int getInterfaceIndex(char *ifaceName) {

    int sockfd;
    struct ifreq ifr;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        ERROR("Could not retrieve interface index for %s", ifaceName);
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifaceName, IFNAMSIZ);
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) < 0) {
        PERROR("failed to request hardware address for %s", ifaceName);
        close(sockfd);
        return -1;
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return ifr.ifr_ifindex;
}

bool InitSocket(char *ifaceName) {
    int IfIndex;
    struct sockaddr_ll sll;

    IfIndex = getInterfaceIndex(ifaceName);
    if (IfIndex < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    /* create the socket */
    if ((eventSock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))) < 0) {
        PERROR("failed to initialize raw socket");
        return false;
    }

    /* binding to the interface */
    memset(&sll, 0, sizeof(sll));
    sll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sll.sll_ifindex = IfIndex;
    sll.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);

    /* Bind the socket to the interface */
    if (bind(eventSock, (struct sockaddr *) &sll, sizeof(sll)) < 0) {
        PERROR("failed to bind raw event socket");
        return false;
    }
    
    /* bpf bytecode to filter only PTP packets (ethertype 0x88f7)
     * obtained via "tcpdump -dd ether proto 0x88f7" */
//  struct sock_filter filter_ptp[] = {
//          { 0x28, 0, 0, 0x0000000c }, // ldh [12]
//          { 0x15, 0, 1, 0x000088f7 }, // jeq #0x88f7 jt 2 jf 3
//          { 0x06, 0, 0, 0x00040000 }, // ret #262144
//          { 0x06, 0, 0, 0x00000000 }, // ret #0
//  };
//
//  struct sock_fprog bpf_ptp = { .len = 4, .filter = filter_ptp, };
//
//  if (setsockopt(eventSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, &bpf_ptp,
//                 sizeof(bpf_ptp))) {
//      PERROR("failed attaching filter to raw event socket");
//      return false;
//  }
}

int waitForData(struct timeval * timeout, fd_set *readfds) {
    int ret, nfds;
    struct timeval tv, *tv_ptr;

    if (timeout) {
        tv.tv_sec = timeout->tv_sec;
        tv.tv_usec = timeout->tv_usec;
        tv_ptr = &tv;
    } else {
        tv_ptr = NULL;
    }

    FD_ZERO(readfds);
    nfds = 0;

    FD_SET(eventSock, readfds);
    nfds = eventSock;
    nfds++;

    ret = select(nfds, readfds, 0, 0, tv_ptr);
    return ret;
}

void netr(void) {
    ssize_t ret = 0;
    char buf[1024];
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct iovec vec[1];
    struct sockaddr_in from_addr;

    union {
        struct cmsghdr cm;
        char control[256];
    } cmsg_un;

    struct cmsghdr *cmsg;

    vec[0].iov_base = buf;
    vec[0].iov_len = PACKET_SIZE;

    memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
    memset(&from_addr, 0, sizeof(from_addr));
    memset(buf, 0, PACKET_SIZE);
    memset(&cmsg_un, 0, sizeof(cmsg_un));

    msg.msg_name = (caddr_t) & from_addr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(from_addr);
    msg.msg_iov = vec;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg.msg_control = cmsg_un.control;
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(cmsg_un.control);
    msg.msg_flags = 0;

    ret = recvmsg(eventSock, &msg, MSG_DONTWAIT);
    if (ret < 0) {
        PERROR("failed to receive message!");
    }

    INFO("received Bytes: %ld", ret);
    printBuffer(msg.msg_iov->iov_base, PACKET_SIZE);
}

int main(void) {
    int ret;
    fd_set readfds;
    struct timeval timeout = { .tv_sec = 1, .tv_usec = 0 };

    INFO("main started!!");

    InitSocket(PTP_IF_NAME);

    while (1) {
        INFO("waiting for event!!");
        ret = waitForData(&timeout, &readfds);
        INFO("select return = %d", ret);
        if (ret > 0) {
            if (FD_ISSET(eventSock, &readfds)) {
                netr();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get error messages from one of the different operations? I tried your code on my machine and, provided I change the interface name (I used `lo`) and launch it as root, it does print the Ethernet frames in my case (from `ping 127.0.0.1`). If you get no error, did you try running it with `strace`?

Comment: its not giving any errors, I opened wireshark in parallel to check Ethernet activity and the strange thing is that my program starting capturing the frames too, once I stopped wireshark, my program couldn't capture packets anymore and select returned with 0

also, I tried to use lo and ping 127.0.0.1 and it was working fine and captured all the

Comment: Maybe your frames are not addressed to your machine? Sounds like you should try setting your interface to promiscuous mode, Wireshark would typically do that when you use it to capture packets. `sudo ip link set enx503eaa33fc9d promisc on` (then with `off` when you're done).

Comment: @Qeole Thanks a lot it worked, That's what I was missing :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! I turned it into a regular answer. I hope you get your filter working next :).

Comment: Aside: `if ((usedBytes + SIZE_OF_BYYE_PRINT_BLOCK) > SIZE_OF_PRINT_BUFFER)` should be `if ((usedBytes + SIZE_OF_BYYE_PRINT_BLOCK + 1) > SIZE_OF_PRINT_BUFFER)`, but since `usedBytes` increments by 3, makes no difference here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that nothing is wrong with your code itself. This can be verified by running your program on the localhost interface, for example, by changing only this line:

```c
#define PTP_IF_NAME               "lo"
```

And by sending frames, `ping 127.0.0.1`.

Based on the discussion in comments, you can apparently see the frames when Wireshark is running and dumping packets on the interface, but it doesn't work the rest of the time. This is likely a sign that you need to **set your interface to “promiscuous mode”**.

Promiscuous mode tells your card to capture all packets, even those that are not addressed to the interface (those for which the destination MAC address is not the one of the interface). When the mode is off, the card drops packets that it is not supposed to receive, no matter what BPF filter you use or whether you use a filter at all. In your case, it simply looks like you are running your test with packets that are not addressed to the NIC. When Wireshark runs it sets the interface to promiscuous, which also reflects with your program and allows you to see the frames. When you stop it, it restores the interface into non-promiscuous.

You don't have to run Wireshark to set the interface to promiscuous mode, you can do it with:

```
$ sudo ip link set enx503eaa33fc9d promisc on
```

Then disable with `off` once you are done. Alternatively, just sending packets with the correct destination MAC address should make them visible without changing the NIC configuration :).

Answer (score 0):

Promiscuous mode is not efficient. You need to register the PTP multicast address with SIOCADDMULTI ioctl command.